# Find string inside an array stored in a data-attribute

Tags: jquery, html

My HTML data attribute will have array of strings like "Thisissampletext","Thisismaintext"

I am passing this data attribute to Jquery, we have to alert if the data attribute contains 'sample' within the string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us what you have so far

Comment: <div class='mainText' data-text=[arrayhere]></div><script='text/javascript'>
if ($(.mainText).attr('data-text').has('sample')
alert("Sample text here");
</script>

Comment: you can edit your question to put code in...what about the js, what have you tried?

Comment: @JasonSperske: no.. I am trying for the way to find the text inside the string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be something along these lines

```
var needle = "sample";
var haystack = $('.mainText').data("text");
if(haystack.indexOf(needle) != -1){
   //DO CODE HERE
}
```

Depending on what your data is called and what object it is attached to

Edit: Added Correct Field Names

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact you've clearly not tried anything and wrote your js snippet out quickly here, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. Note the use of single quotes:

```
<div class='mainText' data-text='["string1", "something"]'></div>

$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var arr = $(".mainText").data('text');
    for (var i =0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == "something") 
                alert("win");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6LAEB/